# Uploading 600 images into a mysqldatabase via cronjob

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cronjob that runs every 5 minutes and I need to fetch about 600 images.

I cannot store those images in the filesystem using php - it takes allot of time to save even 1 image, and the shared hosting I'm in cannot cope with uploading and deleting 600 images every 5 minutes.

So I am thinking of uploading them to a separate database, with only a single table inside.

Do you think mysql can cope with this?

Any better ideas on how to do this?

Ty

Comment: images of what? from where? used for what purpose?

Comment: Images from an xml feed - affiliate site -

Comment: I think you need to identify where the bottleneck is first before trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving images you claim are so large that even the file system can’t cope with them, but you want to save them instead in an SQL table.  SQL is going to be even slower than accessing the file system, not to mention all the slack you’ll create in the table from constant updates.  Seems to me you might want to look into a virtual dedicated server with enough horsepower to accomplish your task.  Shared hosting isn’t for everything—-usually it’s good for small, low IO type sites or development of larger sites which will be moved into a production environment with many more resources later.

Answer (score 2):

I would not suggest loading images into a database. Read speed would not be as fast, and would require too much resources to run. Why not load the images into an external web storage service like Amazon EC2 / S3 data storage?

Comment: EC2 is not a storage platform, but S3 would be a great choice

Comment: EC2 has EBS options for storage and there is nothing wrong with using them for that purpose. Matter of fact, EBS is stored by Amazon on S3 automatically.

Comment: EC2 storage is volititle, and yes EBS is another option

Comment: I am trying to get a sense of the task in hand - of uploading 600 images - one after another from a cronjob - is this a walk in the park for a great host? or a big task?  - the images are not very big, mostly under 640 x 480 res

Comment: for AWS configured with load balancer etc, everything is a walk in the park :-)

Comment: Start with a spot-small Amazon EC2 instance and run a test. See how long it takes your task to complete. If it’s too slow, move up to medium, repeat.  Then large, etc. Find what works for you. That’s the whole point of cloud EC2.

Comment: actully no that's vertical, you want horizontal its more efficient to run up extra EC2 instances than to buy larger ones

Comment: @Dragon, since the EC2 resources are identical in scale exponentially vertical as horizontal, the first run of tests, resource planning, should be vertical.  If a medium does it then you could break that down into 2 smalls.  Same amount of compute units, but easier for an initial scalability test going vertical.

Answer (score 2):

If the file system cannot handle it, a mysql server on the same host can definitly not handle it (after all, it accesses that same file system). If the database runs on a different host, you have additional overhead due to network traffic and it is even less likely that the network connection can handle it.

Comment: Please tell me, uploading 600 images, is a normal or a huge task (i mean in general). Or for a dedicated server it's just a walk in the park?

Comment: not all dedicated server's are the same, there are an infinite number of variations, but sure you can buy one that would make this task a 'walk in the park'

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain the requirements very clearly, but lets assume you need to download 600 images every 5 minutes over the next month. If it were me, I would looking into a NoSql API (i.e [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)) for reading/writing the images directly to the filesystem, and implement a queueing API (i.e. [Gearman](http://gearman.org/gearman)) to afford the ability to parallel process multiple images at once.

Basically it would work like this:

- Curl for images you need
- Input the image urls into the queue, as a "payload"
- Assign a worker to process the payload. This would include downloading, resizing, and storing the resulting image via the NoSQL API

With this solution you could cron every 5 minutes, and if the queueing api is smart enough it will ensure no duplicate entries, and you wouldn't have to worry about the cron not finishing from the previous run, as it's only job is to add entries to the queue.

Also, you can increase the number of workers based on your hardware setup, so if you don't have much ram or cpu, set the worker limit to 2, and as you scale up/out, you can increase the worker limit accordingly.

Another consideration is if the images are to be accessed from other servers, outside of a httpd service, for which you will need to consider a network filesystem like NFS, or [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/).

It will definitely take more work on the outset, but as you can see, provide you a longer shelf life for handling this type of work.